# Firemonkey Android InputStream reads 0s for files larger than 1MB

Tags: android, android-intent, inputstream, firemonkey

My Firemonkey Android app launches for multiple file types including zip files.  When I check the intent and try to read the file that launched my app, I read 0s for files over 1MB.  I don't know the exact size limits.  A 1.7KB file reads correctly, a 1.36MB file does not.  It reads the correct number of bytes, and after reading 0s for about 2/3s of the file, it finally starts reading actual file data from the beginning of the file. This is my first attempt at such things.  I created simplified test code to explore the problem:

```
  function StartupFileGet : string;
  var
    intent: JIntent;
    uri: Jnet_Uri;
    uriStr: String;
    InStrm: Androidapi.Jni.Javatypes.JInputStream;
    ch: Char;
    total: integer;
  begin
    result := '';
    intent := TAndroidHelper.Activity.getIntent;
    if intent <> nil then
    begin
      if TJIntent.JavaClass.ACTION_VIEW.equals(intent.getAction) then
      begin
        uri := intent.getData;
        uriStr := JStringToString(uri.toString);
        result := uriStr;
        result := result + '=';
        InStrm := TAndroidHelper.Activity.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
        if InStrm <> nil then
        begin
          total := InStrm.available;
          if  total > 0 then
          begin
            try
              ch := Char(InStrm.read());
              if ch = #0 then ch := #$30;
              result := result + ch;
              ch := Char(InStrm.read());
              if ch = #0 then ch := #$30;
              result := result + ch;
            except
              result := result + ', exception';
            end;
            result := result + ', ';
            result := result + IntToStr(total);
          end;
        end;
        InStrm.close;
      end;
    end;
  end;
```

Incorrect result with a 1.36MB zip file is:
Startup file: content://com.google.android.apps.nbu.files.provider/2/1044=00, 1362165

Correct result with a 1.7KB zip file is:
Startup file: content://com.google.android.apps.nbu.files.provider/2/1045=PK, 1697

In both the above results, the file sizes are correct.  Android 9, both files are in the downloads folder.  Rad Studio 10.4.1

Comment: `ch := Char(InStrm.read());` You only read two bytes. Where is the loop that does that a 'total' times?

Comment: This is simplified test code returning a simple result I can post.  If I can find the problem and read the first two bytes correctly, the rest of the file will probably also read correctly.